# How do we access a php variable in angular js?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have this variable `$name = 'test'` in one of the php files. How do I access this in javascript?

I can create a hidden input element and get the value by id, but there are some issues with that, so may I know if there are any other options to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there's two possible ways.

First - Get from HTML

`<input type='hidden' value="<?=$name?>" id="name-varirable">`

```
//JS file
$scope.name = angular.element('#name-vairiable').val();
```

Second - Write an API to expose that value

```
//Your Angular Controller
$http.get(url).then(function(success){
    $scope.name = success.data
});
```

Based on your use case whichever suits your needs better.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I work for large government company in UK, business applications tend to use APIs to expose backend values, this allows a clear division between FE and BE code and when, for example, installing software on, for example, docker containers, only the relevant software need be installed on the FE container and the BE container, there is a total separation of concerns

Comment: i consider the latter approach to be professional, the former to be amateur

Comment: PS nice answer btw very succinct +1

Answer (score 2):

You just give it to the js script by:

```
<html>
....
<script>
var name = <?php echo $name; ?>;
</script>
....
```

Or:

```
var name = <?= $name ?>;
```

Comment: Or use the shorthand `<?=$name?>` - Handy and small when you need to do this a few times. Basically `<?=` means start PHP and echo whatever comes next.